# How to apply Font type for a whole application in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, truetype, android-fonts

I want to apply Font type without using XML. By code, I want to change Font type and it should be able to apply for a whole application, when I click Arial else Times New Roman etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reccomend having a list preference, in a preference screen. You can then set the fonts from that. i.e:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
String font = sp.getString("font","-1")
if(font.equals("timesroman")) {
TypeFace  typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "timesnewroman.ttf");
}
else if(font.equals("arial")) {
TypeFace  typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
}
TextView view= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
view.setTypeface(typeFace)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code to change the font of app

```
TypeFace  typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
TextView view= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
view.setTypeface(typeFace)
```

Comment: What is that "font.ttf". It is a XML file right ? Without using XML, in my main code i have to apply Font type . For that i have to write a code. How could i do this ?

Comment: it is the font lib that u can download from internet and it is .ttf type download it from internet and copy into your asset folder

Comment: .ttf stand for True Type Font library